# What is the programming paradigm when I just use functions in a file to organize my program?

Tags: object-oriented, python, programming-practices, paradigms

I'm programming a telegram bot with Python and, for a number of reasons, there are no classes in the whole project, just several functions correlated to the the file where they are located. E.g., my `parse()` method is defined inside a parser.py file.

If I'm not structuring the project in terms of classes and objects and states and attributes, then what paradigm is this? None?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The programming paradigm that organizes the software into functions is called *procedural programming*. For example, C is a procedural programming language. Most dynamic languages like JS or Python can be used in a procedural style.

While you are also organizing your code into separate files, there is no commonly used name that describes this. For example, *modular programming* is more about encapsulation than about using multiple files.

It is perfectly fine if you aren't writing classes. OOP is nice but is not always a good fit. For many problems, a procedural approach is great.

**Further Reading**
[Procedural programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming)

Comment: You can use OOP languages in a procedural way too, especially if the language contains "free" functions.  [`using static` in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#using-static)

Comment: At the moment, your answer is plain wrong. "*organiz[ing] the software into functions*" is also what happens in functional languages. So without knowing more about the structure of the OP's code, there is no way to know for sure whether they are using a procedural or functional approach.

Comment: @DavidArno No. The terms procedures/subroutines/methods/functions are used interchangeably by most programmers. While they do have distinct meanings (functions are mappings, procedures produce side effects, methods belong to objects), most languages use a single term for all meanings so that in C or Python the term “function” also describes “procedures”. Functional programming is more than using functions and typically describes (a) a certain declarative approach, or (b) a programming style using higher-order functions. It would be rare for FP to happen by accident.

Comment: You have no idea whether the OP is using a declarative or imperative style and thus you have no way of knowing whether they are using a functional or procedural paradigm. But regardless of that, the statement "*The programming paradigm that organizes the software into functions is called procedural programming*" is false as there are two programming paradigms that organise software into functions: functional and procedural. It's likely that you have guessed correctly with regard to the style used by the OP, but your opening sentence remains wrong.

Comment: @DavidArno We could have a long conversation about the history of programming paradigms, but the TL;DR is that paradigms are somewhat vague and overlapping. E.g. Lisp is procedural-functional-imperative, Haskell is functional-declarative (not procedural!), C# and Python are imperative-procedural-OO-functional. While structured, procedural, modular, and class based OO programming are all about *organizing* code to some degree, other paradigms like functional, imperative, declarative, or actor programming are more about a *style* of problem solving. I stand by my opening sentence.